# How to pull docker image on remote machine using java?

Tags: java, docker, docker-machine, spotify-docker-client

I want to pull image on remote docker-machine so I found one git repo which will run docker using java.

So I tried using the following way,

1. First I configured a docker setup

```
    final DockerClient docker = DefaultDockerClient.builder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://remote ipaddress:port"))
        .dockerCertificates(new DockerCertificates(docker certificate path))
        .build();
```

2. host configured

```
    final HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig.builder().build();
```

3. Pull image

```
docker.pull("image name");
```

4. Creating container with ContainerConfig

```
final ContainerConfig containerConfig = ContainerConfig.builder()
                        .hostConfig(hostConfig)
                        .image("image name")
                        .cmd("sh", "-c", "while :; do sleep 1; done")
                        .build();
```

5. Deploying docker container at remote location

```
final ContainerCreation creation = docker.createContainer(containerConfig);
                    final String id = creation.id();
```

6. Start container

```
docker.startContainer(id);
```

After following all the step I am not able to pull image on remote docker configuration pc.

So as a conclusion I want to run docker from the current machine to provided remote docker configuration using java. If you have any idea how can I achieve please let me know.

Comment: What step isn't working?  What error do you get?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am getting an error like failed: Connection refused: connect, Timeout, etc. On the docker pull image steps not working